# pyspark saveAsTextFile works for python 2.7 but not 3.4

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running pyspark on an Amazon EMR cluster. I have a very simple test script to see if I can write data to s3 using spark-submit ...

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
numbers = sc.parallelize(range(100))
numbers.saveAsTextFile("s3n://my-bucket/test.txt")
sc.stop()
```

When I run this script using spark-submit in a python2.7 environment, it works just fine. But when I try to run the same script in a python3.4 environment, I get the following traceback ...

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../pyspark/worker.py", line 161, in main 
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
File ".../pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
File ".../pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
File ".../pyspark/serializers.py", line 419, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'unicode' on <module 'builtins' (built-in)>
```

I'm manipulating my python environment using conda and by setting the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` variables.

Is there an issue using `saveAsTextFile` in python 3? Or am I missing a step in setting up my python 3 environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like this has nothing to do with python3, and everything to do with my conda environment. In short, I set up a conda environment in my `bootstrap.sh`, but I only actually activated it on the master node. So the master node was using conda python, but the workers were using system python.

My solution now is to set `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/hadoop/miniconda3/envs/myenv/python`.

Is there a better way to activate my conda environment on the worker nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your EMR cluster is configured to use pyspark 2.7, while you are running python 3.4 which might cause a problem when using with pyspark 2.7

The following link describe how to configure Amazon EMR to use spark with python 3.4

> I know Python 3.4.3 is installed on an Amazon EMR cluster instances,
>   but the default Python version used by Spark and other programs is
>   Python 2.7.10. How do I change the default Python version to Python 3
>   and run a pyspark job?

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/

---

There is the different implementation of the `range()` function in Python2 vs Python3.

In Python2 `range()` returns `a list of numbers`.
In Python2 `range()` returns `a generator`.

So when you are using Python3, the input you provide is a `generator` instead of `list of numbers`

**More info about the different between `range()` in python2 vs python3:**

*Python2*
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range
 range(start, stop[, step])

> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised).

Example:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

*Python 3*
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range
**range(start, stop[, step])**

> Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence
>   type, as documented in Ranges and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

```
>>> range(10)
range(0, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I replaced `range(100)` with `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and I added a `configuration.json` that defines `"PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"`. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3